# How to set fix ImageView size inside TableViewCell programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have this issue wherein I need to fix the size on an image inside a tableviewcell. The image below shows that the **image size** in not uniform.

[image]

Here are the codes I used.

```
 if noteImageIsAvailable == true {
        if let imageData = assignedNotePhoto?.photoData {
            if let image = Utilities.resizePictureImage(UIImage(data: imageData as Data)) {
                //added fix
                cell.imageView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: 36, height: 24)
                cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
                //-----
                cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                cell.imageView?.image = image
            }
        }
    }
```

I read an answer here in stackoverflow. It says I need to add `clipToBounds` but unfortunately it doesn't work. Please help me solve this issue. Thank you

**TableView Code**

```
extension SettingNoteViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Menu.SettingNote.items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
    let keyPass = KeyHelper.NoteSetting.info[indexPath.row]
    let assignedNotePhoto = self.getNotePhoto(key: keyPass.key)
    let assignedNoteTextData = self.getNoteTextData(key: keyPass.key)?.value

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .black
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = .white
    cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    let noteImageIsAvailable = assignedNotePhoto?.photoData != nil

    if noteImageIsAvailable == true {
        if let imageData = assignedNotePhoto?.photoData {
            if let image = Utilities.resizePictureImage(UIImage(data: imageData as Data)) {
                //added fix
                cell.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                cell.imageView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: 36, height: 24)
                cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
                //-----
                cell.imageView?.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
                cell.imageView?.image = image
            }
        }
    }
    cell.textLabel?.text = Menu.SettingNote.items[indexPath.row].value
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = assignedNoteTextData ?? "noteSettingSubTitle".localized

    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.destination is InputMemoViewController {
        let vc = segue.destination as! InputMemoViewController
        vc.infoNoteKey = self.infoNoteKeyToPass
        vc.infoLabelText = self.infoLabelToPass
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.infoNoteKeyToPass = KeyHelper.NoteSetting.info[indexPath.row].key
    self.infoLabelToPass = KeyHelper.NoteSetting.info[indexPath.row].label
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showInputMemo", sender: self)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return 80
   }
}
```

The image below was the output when I applied @Kishan Bhatiya solution. 
[image: output]

The first and second image is a landscape photo and the third image is in portrait
[image: output2]

Comment: How about adding `cell.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` to your code?

Comment: show your tableView Code. Have you created UITableViewCell or not?

Comment: @nwyyy Hi, I also tried to add it but still doesn't work

Comment: @HabinLama Hi, I added the code for `TableView` , I did not add `tableviewcell` in my storyboard

Comment: Remove `cell.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and check because if `AutoLayout` enabled then `frame` has no effect or you can check my answer

Comment: Try using heightanchor and widthanchor if that does not help then make designs in `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `cell.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` then `frame` has no effect, so try to use any one

```
    let marginguide = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide


    //imageView auto layout constraints

    cell.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let marginguide = cell.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

    cell.imageView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginguide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    cell.imageView?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginguide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    cell.imageView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    cell.imageView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 20 //half of your width or height
```

And it's better to set constraints in `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to fix it using your solution, it works but it affects the layout of the `Title` and `SubTitle`. Kindly check the added image above. It was the output when I used your solution.  Thank you

Comment: Set `Title` and `SubTitle`'s leading anchor as cell's `imageView` trailing anchor if you are set constraints using `AutoLayout`

Comment: Sorry, how to do it? :D

Comment: It's better to create these constraints in `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works now. I just have to fix the separator because It is not align with the `title` and `subtitle` when image is landscape. Thank you so much. :D

Answer (score 3):

you know your imageview size. So you can resize your UIImage to imageView size.

```
extension UIImage{
    func resizeImageWithHeight(newW: CGFloat, newH: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newW, height: newH))
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newW, height: newH))
        
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return newImage
    }
}
```

use like that

```
let img = originalImage.resizeImageWithHeight(newW: 40, newH: 40)
cell.imageView?.image = img
```

Here, 40 40 is my imageview size

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, `scaleAspectFit` is solved for me. you can try it

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
```